# Expressing $x$ and $z$ as functions of $y$ (non-generate matrix)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system
$$
\dot{x}=x-z+y^2,\quad\dot{y}=x-2y+z+y^2+2x^2z,\quad\dot{z}=-2x+2y+z^2-y^2.
$$

and the equilibrium $(0,0,0)$.

Now, there is used some statement that I did not know yet:

> > Since
> >     $$
> > \frac{\partial (x-z+y^2,x-2y+z+y^2+2x^2z)}{\partial(x,z)}_{|(x,y,z)=0}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}~~~(*)
> > $$
> >     is a non-degenerate matrix, one can find $x$ and $z$ as functions of $y$ from the first two equations:
> >     $$
> > x=y+y^3+O(y^4),\quad z=y-y^2-y^3+O(y^4).~~(**)
> > $$

First of all, what is the left-hand side of $(*)$?

Then, how do we get $(**)$?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not aware of representing derivatives as matrices. [This](http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix)
might be helpful. The second question is an exercise in power series approximation.

Comment: The first question is clear now. The second question is not clear completely: Let $f(x,y,z):=x-z+y^2$. Then, the Taylor expansion reduces to be $f(x,y,z)=f_x(0,0,0)x+f_y(0,0,0)+f_z(0,0,0)+\frac{1}{2}f_{yy}(0,0,0)y^2+\frac{1}{3!}f_{yyy}(0,0,0)y^3+O(y^4)$. How does this give $x=y+y^3+O(y^4)$?